# Syntax of ArrayFire for C++ (multiplying array by scalar)

Tags: c++, arrayfire, vector-multiplication

I have gone through the documentation and looked at examples, but I am having trouble understanding the syntax of "operator(star)".

For example, if I have an array called "array1", and I want to multiply it by a value, 3, how would I incorporate the syntax:

array& operator*=   (   const array &   val ) ?

I am new to C++, and new to ArrayFire. Thank you!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Based on the ArrayFire [page](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__array__mem__operator__multiply__eq.htm), this function "Multiplies the value(s) of val to the elements of the array." I'm not sure how that operator, then, cannot multiply an array by a value. Again, new to C++ -- any additional explanation would be helpful. In the meantime, I'll work on getting a book on C++.

Comment: That page lists multiple overloads. The one you showed in your question is not the one that would be used to multiply an object by a value, but by another array.

Comment: Great, thanks! As I mentioned, I'm new to ArrayFire -- could you offer the correct implementation / an example of what I'm looking for?